# Having multiple ViewModel instances via Fragments in ViewPager

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-viewmodel

I have a structure like this:

```
MainActivity
    ListFragment
        DetailFragment
            ViewPager
                DetailItemFragment
                DetailItemFragment
                DetailItemFragment
                .
                .
```

I have `DetailItemViewModel` which remains as a field in `DetailItemFragment`. I want to create different view model instances for each `DetailItemFragment`. However, the system gives me the same instance. I create it like this:

```
detailItemViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(DetailItemViewModel::class.java)
```

`this` is the object of `DetailItemFragment` so the scope must be in that fragment. I expect each `DetailItemFragment` creates its own view model instance. But the `factory` creates one instance when it is injected in `MainActivity`. I don't know the main reason but I am suspicious about my dagger structure so any approach about it will be appreciated.

**EDIT**

ViewModelFactory class:

```
@PerActivity
class ViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
    private val creators: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        val creator = creators[modelClass] ?: creators.entries.firstOrNull {
        modelClass.isAssignableFrom(it.key)
        }?.value ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class $modelClass")
        try {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return creator.get() as T
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What happens inside your `ViewModelFactory`? May be it's returning you previous version of `ViewModel` for every new instances.

Comment: Yes it gives me previously-created-instance of that viewmodel. I share its code below EDIT title.

Comment: Remove factory from your `ViewModelProviders` syntax and it would give you distinct instances of `VIewModel`s for each new `Fragment` instances.

Comment: @JeelVankhede It cannot be created without factory, because it has injected constructor containing injected parameters.

Comment: Okay, then you'll need to modify your `ViewModelFactory` to give unique instance for every new fragment instance. *(I.e. making another factory for unique instances)*

Comment: 1. Remove `@PerActivity` from the `ViewModelFactory`. 2. How are you getting the factory in the fragment? 3. How are you providing it using dagger?

Comment: There is a good chance that you have `@Singleton` on your ViewModel and you don't actually want it. You want it unscoped.